# Stealth and invisibility

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Under [*invisibility*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/invisibility.html) it says:

> Of course, the subject is not magically silenced [...] If a check is required, a stationary invisible creature has a +40 bonus on its Stealth checks. This bonus is reduced to +20 if the creature is moving. The spell ends if the subject attacks any creature.

Does this mean that when somebody is trying to hear an invisibile creature, the invisible creature still gets +20 on her Stealth check when moving, even though invisibility should not interfere with auditory senses.

The question comes from the sense vs RAW side of things.

Comment: I am asking if other creatures trying to hear this person approaching using only auditory means still have to deal with the +20(or if not approaching 40)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the invisible creature is stationary he gets a +40 to his stealth check.

If the invisible creature is moving he only gets +20 to his stealth check.

The act of rolling a perception check to detect a stealthy invisible creature is completely unrelated and unaffected when trying to sense using 'auditory senses only'. A standard perception check takes all senses into account.  (If pathfinder was more simluationist then you might actually provide a penalty to the perception check when using 'auditory only' because they may miss some visual clues an invisible creature makes other than sound, such as footprints or a tree branch swaying)

Comment: Re posting the original question text is not helpful. Especially in a game with thousands of rules, when asking the validity of rule A in situation B there is more to consider then just rule A.

Comment: I tend to disagree - what the rules say here is pretty clear, and so trying to restate the rules so that they click with you is a legitimate approach.  I'm unclear why you have the question otherwise - yes, the bonus is only +20 when moving.

Comment: Point taken. I think a good reply is to take this rule and combine it with a different rule Stealth:You are skilled at avoiding detection, allowing you to slip past foes or strike from an unseen position. This skill covers hiding and moving silently.  Put together it shows that stealth is specific to moving and hiding and invisibility would not help you do things other then that "stealthly"(such as casting a spell)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, he gets a bonus when he is required to make a Stealth Check.

This means that creatures trying to hear him if he is invisible have more difficulty than if he was simply stealthy (not invisible)

This does not mean creatures get a penalty on Perception checks, Stealth is a separate thing.

I'll also add that if the character is not attempting to make a stealth check, (for example he is running past a monster) the monster will be able to tell where he is, even though it won't be able to see him.

Here are a scenario:

- My sorcerer hears an ogre down the hall and casts invisibility on himself.
- As the ogre approaches I hold my breath to make sure he doesn't notice me (stealth check +40 since I am stationary)
- After the ogre passes, I attempt to move silently away from it in the other direction (stealth check +20, I'm moving now)

Comment: Perception is used to see stealth is what I meant, not that you cannot see well.

Comment: @Kendric correct, a perception roll versus your stealth skill + the bonus from invisibility (20 or 40) + a d20 would be the check to actually hear you while you are invisible

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean when somebody trying to hear an invisibile creature, that invisibile creature gets +20 to stealth when moving or flying.

He gets +20 to stealth when moving or flying *even when someone isn't trying to hear him* as long as he is invisible per the spell you already quoted.